# How to group a series of numbers?

Tags: clustering

Apologies if this is a simple question, this is my first time here, and I am a noob at statistics.
I have a series of numbers and I want to find cutoff points that clearly separate, or group, the data.

Say I have this data:

[image]

You can see it is clearly grouped into two groups, the large values, and the small values.  (Maybe 3 groups, with that first positive value being a group of its own.)

Is there any algorithm to determine these groups automatically/programmatically?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm guessing there's a term for this that I'm just not aware of. I have the same problem. I'm basically trying to group power readings into "device on" and "device standby" groups, but they can overlap with different devices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you eventually found it, but this source was helpful to me:
https://www.real-statistics.com/multivariate-statistics/cluster-analysis/jenks-natural-breaks/